# How do I get the information displayed on a site?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

sorry if it's obvious but I've been looking into documentation and can't find anything. So I'm making Spring app and I need it to get the information displayed under specific URL into my java code. When I try to use f.e. GetUrlContents it displays the html script but not the values visible on a site.

Let's say the script calls some method that displays "hello" on the site. I don't want the script but solely the "hello".

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the content by using the openStream() method. This will get the whole html content of the webpage and then use ***.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");** to extract the content alone from the webpage you are giving, Refer to the followig code snippet,

```
import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class ReadingWebPage {
       public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
          //Instantiating the URL class
          URL url = new URL("http://www.something.com/");
          //Retrieving the contents of the specified page
          Scanner sc = new Scanner(url.openStream());
          //Instantiating the StringBuffer class to hold the result
          StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
          while(sc.hasNext()) {
             sb.append(sc.next());
             //System.out.println(sc.next());
          }
          //Retrieving the String from the String Buffer object
          String result = sb.toString();
          System.out.println(result);
          //Removing the HTML tags
          result = result.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");
          System.out.println("Contents of the web page: "+result);
       }
    }
```

Output

```
<html><body><h1>Itworks!</h1></body></html>
Contents of the web page: Itworks!
```

If you need more information do refer to this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-read-the-contents-of-a-webpage-into-a-string-in-java)